# Isobel,whose brother he was..or...was he

Tags: clauses

What is the grammatically correct clause?

1. Isobel,whose brother he was,(had heard the joke before.)  or
2. Isobel,whose brother was he,(had heard the joke before.)

Comment: Isn't Isobel usually a female name?

Comment: Do you mean that, before this sentence, you were talking about the _brother_, not Isobel? Please provide more context.

Comment: Don't even bother trying to decide which version is "correct". Just find a less roundabout way of saying it - for example, *"His brother Isobel [had blad blah]"*. But like snailboat, I never heard of *Isobel* as a ***male*** name.

Comment: I thought Isobel was primarily a female name also, but it didn't seem relevant to the question about the clause, so I ignored the gender and assumed the name was just a placeholder.

Comment: I think "Isobel" being a female name changes the context, and I've answered accordingly. It makes sense if you insert (for example) "Bob told a joke." before the given sentences.

Comment: Isobel could be a surname, although I've only ever seen it with spelled with an "a" like "Isabel". Regardless, I still think the gender is irrelevant because the question wasn't about the sentence, it was about the clause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Surely *he* refers to somebody mentioned previously in the discourse - perhaps the teller of the joke?

Comment: @StoneyB: Surely the fact that it does my head in to "decode" this relationship can't just be down to me being disoriented by the use of a female name in a context that can only refer to a male? I don't see any way to parse *whose brother he was* as anything other than a parenthetical clause - which makes it *optional*, in which case ***Isobel*** is the subject (the one who's heard the joke before). The only other thing we know is that Isobel is the brother of some guy mentioned earlier *(**his** brother, whose brother **he** was)*, which both you and I presumably agree on.

Comment: ...belay that! I can now see the alternative parsing. Talk about awkward phrasing!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would write it *"Isobel, his brother, had heard the joke before."* You might also write it *"Isobel, who was his brother, had heard the joke before."* I'm assuming that you are using "his brother" to describe "Isobel". Because Isobel is the subject, you would use "who" as a pronoun to refer to Isobel.

"Whose" is a possessive pronoun  *"He was the man whose brother had heard the joke before."* Which brother had heard the joke? The man's brother.

The female gender of the name is adding a lot of confusion, so let's look at an alternative interpretation.

> Isobel,whose brother he was,(had heard the joke before.)

This can mean *"He was Isobel's brother and Isobel had heard the joke before."*.

If we remove the clause, we get *"Isobel had heard the joke before."* The clause must be trying to describe Isobel's relationship to someone, and because she is female and can't be a brother, "he" must mean someone other than Isobel that is her brother.

The obvious way to rephrase would be *"Isobel, his sister, had heard the joke before."* Although *"Isobel, whose brother he was,"* sounds awkward, I think that it is technically correct.

I still think that it is more likely that the poster chose a random name and a random relationship to create an example sentence to ask about, but it is possible that the poster knew how to construct "whose brother he was" but didn't know how to construct the clause as "his sister".

Without clarification from the original poster, we don't really know which is the intended meaning.

Comment: I hope @Dinusha Maduranga will come back and explain how this can possibly be the right answer, when the original sentences say that somebody ("he") was Isobel's brother, not that Isobel was somebody's brother.

Comment: I agree with @Scott. In the asker's example, "he" is the brother of the subject of "whose". The subject of whose is "Isobel", so the sentence is attempting to describe someone as Isobel's brother, rather than describing Isobel as someone's brother. This answer *looks* correct because "brother" is a bi-directional relationship so the alternate writing "Isobel, his brother..." has the same ultimate meaning, but if the relationship were more uni-directional (e.g. "Isobel, whose *boss* he was...) then this answer's incorrectness would be more obvious.

Comment: This is clearly wrong. Isobel is a woman's name so Isobel is unlikely to be anyone's brother.

Answer (score 7):

Of the two, the following sentence is better:

> Isobel, whose brother he was, had heard the joke before.

However, I wouldn't use this formulation at all, because it's really confusing - note how many people commenting and answering so far have thought that "Isobel" and "brother" refer to the same person in the sentence! To reduce confusion, I would recast this to:

> Isobel, his sister, had heard the joke before.

Comment: The confusion comes about only because the sentence is presented in isolation. But, yes, "Isobel, his sister, ..." would be much clearer, even if the omitted context was present.

Comment: @ZsigE: I agree with everything you say, but I would add something that nobody else seems to have mentioned: the OP's second phrasing ("whose brother was he") might make sense in a lyrical/poetic or archaic context, employing an inversion as in "The King, whose humble servant am I, demands your surrender." (or something like that). ... ... It seems to me that there is some well known example of this, from a song, or maybe a Bible verse, but Googling phrases like "am I" and "was he" is remarkably unfruitful.)

Comment: @Scott: Yep, that's definitely valid too. There's at least one Biblical example of this, even in modern translations (Genesis 46:2, ESV: And God spoke to Israel in visions of the night and said, “Jacob, Jacob.” And he said, “**Here am I.**”)